# Initializing object with name vs variable

Tags: php, symfony

(Symfony framework is used) I am trying to initialize object like this

`$token = new $provider;` where `$provider` is `Dropbox` and I am getting this exception

> Attempted to load class "Dropbox" from the global namespace.
>   Did you forget a "use" statement?

But if I change the code to `$token = new Dropbox;` then it works, where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you have declared the `Dropbox` class in a use statement, when creating a class in that method, you need to have the FQDN of the class as the string.
Example;

```
$provider = '\MyBundle\Classes\Provider\Dropbox';
$token = new $provider;
```

Comment: Doesn't the leading `\\` will make the `$provider` as a namespace? Not the class.

Comment: @Chay22 Symfony (well version > 2.8) will happily accept with or without the leading `\` - I've just tested it to confirm

Comment: $provider = Dropbox::class: should also work.  I might add that making a ProviderFactory to hide this sort of stuff is also something to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Worth reading http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php

> [...] there is no difference between a qualified and a fully qualified
>   Name inside a dynamic class name, function name, or constant name [...]

When you reference a classname by a string, you need to define it with fully-qualified namespace.

Prepend it with namespace where the class belong,

```
$class = 'Provider\Namespace\' . $provider;
$class = new $class;
```

Don't also forget to escape the backslash if you prefer double quote

```
$class = "Provider\\Namespace\\$provider";
$class = new $class;
```

If it does exists within the same namespace, simply prepend php predefined constant

```
$class = __NAMESPACE__ . '\' . $provider;
```